# Add google material design icon in css pseudo :after content

Tags: html, css, material-design

I just wanted do add some of googles material design [icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) to the content of a link on hover:

```
a:hover::after {
    content: "<i class="material-icons">link</i>"
}
```

but it does not work, please see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_s/e8dhLhyn/).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
a:hover::after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "link";
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

So you can change the `content: "[whatever icon here]";`

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e8dhLhyn/2/)

Also the fiddle didn't correctly load the icon font so put I placed the link in the html.

Comment: what is -webkit-font-feature-settings ? I got a "Your search - -webkit-font-feature-settings - did not match any documents." in a google search (O.o)

Comment: @gerdi
"The font-feature-settings CSS property gives you control over advanced typographic features in OpenType fonts."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

Comment: It is very important to add: font-feature-settings: 'liga';
If you want your Material Icons to render in Firefox.

Comment: It's edge-case, but I had a case where the font wasn't displaying correctly. The element that the pseudo element was on had a `text-transform: uppercase;` that was causing the text to not match, but it wasn't obvious looking at dev tools so it took a second to figure it out. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: Great! One question: How to change the size of the icon?

Answer (score 5):

C.Schubert was almost there with their answer but if you also want to have IE10+ support you need to add `font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1;` So the finished styling will look like this...

```
a:hover::after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "link";
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1;
}
```

And like C.Schubert said change the `content: "[whatever icon here]";` to your desired icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Material Icon with two or more words then you'll need to use the underscore separator like this:

```
a:hover::after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "chevron_right";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **Material Icons** in css pseudo
try this:

```
.p::before{
   font-family: "Material Icons";
   content: '\F019'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the answers didn't work for me, so I share the solution I found and worked for me.

*(icon: chevron-right)*

```
TheElemnt:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Material Design Icons";
}
TheElement::before{
    content: "\F0142";
}
```